# Drupal 7 Node --> Fields Mapping In Database

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to figure out how nodes are mapped back to the fields they contain for learning purposes. How is this done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you have entities and fields; fields are attached to entities. A node is an implementation of an entity (the node module implements `hook_entity_info()` and other such hooks) so it can have fields.

All field/entity relational data is stored in the tables `field_data_field_x` and `field_revision_field_x` or similar (the latter potentially storing revisions of field data if node revisions are enabled).

The `entity_id` column in those tables is the node's ID, and the `bundle` is the node's content type. The `revision_id` is the revision ID of the node, again only really useful if node revisions are enabled.

**UPDATE**

In Drupal terminology a content type is a `bundle` and `bundle`s are attached to entities (in this case the `node` entity). When you create a new content type it gets stored in the `node_type` table, and when the caches are cleared (which invokes `hook_entity_info` on all modules) the [`node_entity_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_entity_info/7) function builds up a list of bundles from the content types    (have a look at the bit in that function that starts `foreach (node_type_get_names() as $type => $name) {`, `node_type_get_names` gets a list of all content types).

As discussed above fields can be attached to entities, so fields can be attached to nodes with a delta (if you like) of `bundle`.

Comment: How does a content type that gets created in the GUI implement hook_entity_info? I understand how the field data gets stored, but how does the form get created?

Comment: Is it field_config_instance that defines which fields go with what?

Comment: @ChrisMuench: I've updated the answer let me know if you need any clarification it's quite complicated if you haven't delved around inside the core modules before!

Comment: Oh sorry I got the wrong end of the stick I think, yes `field_config_instance` is literally where the field and entity type/bundles are related

Comment: Minor addition. The field storage is pluggable, the field_data and field_revision tables are just the default implementation which is provided by field_storage.module. Other implementations for example allow to store field data in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

In D7, for my case **field_config_instance** table provided me the required info.